# ASP.NET MVC + WF + WCF + SERVICE LAYER how i can use thats all in one project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

i have been developed my last project like below as by last architecture

View -> Controller -> Service Code -> Repository with DDD(Model)

Now i want to use WF and WCF?where are they to be on my last architecture?please tell me show me an example.

Comment: What are the specific requirements of your project? IMHO in most cases WF is an overkill.

Comment: What dou you want to do with WCF? Services for other clients or for presentation? There is no point to use them if you don't know wat to do with them. Please specify you intentions.

Comment: we plan to use web apps.,client apps.(winforms),webservices,console apps.
we have oracle db and ms-sql db,
we have workflows but no more,

Comment: i decied to use wf and wcf but i dont know how can i implement with asp.net mvc and them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mostly I organize my projects as follows:

- Solution.Core
- Solution.Configuration
- Solution.Services
- Solution.Presentation
- Solution.Web

More information about this kind of structure could be found at [Arc wiki](http://wiki.github.com/marektihkan/Arc/arc-application-architecture-guidance)

All service interfaces and domain entities goes to *Core* project. *Services* project contains implementation of *Application Services*. *Contollers* and *View Models* are in *Presentation* project. If my controller needs a service I reference it's interface in *Controller's* constructor and wire it to real implementation via IoC/DI container.

Workflows won't contain only business logic, so I encapsulate business logic as small services/commands and call them from workflows. That leaves workflows to *Services* project.

WCF services implementations should be in *Services* project and interfaces in *Core*.

This way it should look like Controller > Service > Workflow > Uses other services to get a result.

For WCF services it's needed to configure endpoint and it should look Service > Workflow > Uses other services to get a result.

Comment: yes actualy i want a core service as a class library project.all business,validation and workflow activities codes(not wf activies code) contain  in this service.for example if i deciced a workflow engine an this case i have decided to the WF,My WF codes dont any business logic.it calls my core service library when it needs.in the future may be i decided to use other workflow framerowk and i change the WF Framework easly.

Comment: If you want to change WF framework later easily, then I recommend to wrap it or abstract it a bit. Basically you need a pipeline where you add commands, so maybe WF is not really needed.

Comment: i found my answer following link.

http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/video-428.aspx

Comment: Btw this StoreFront series is quite good and if you have time then watch them all.

Answer (score 0):

my service layer have interfaces for example the ICustomerService and impleting of the  CustomerService class.

Beforehand  i called this service class from the CustomerController class after my CustomerService class call the my CustomerRepository class.All workflows are in my ServiceLayer classes by .net remoting or web service between two machine(db server,app server,uı server)

But now i decided use to WF and WCF.but i dont know that where does call Wf my service classes or WCF.i dont know where do i put wc and wcf my project.