# MVC Controllers WCF Service

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using ASP.net MVC3 for my presentation layer and my data access and business logic are exposed through a WCF Service. Should my controllers call the WCF service or should there be a further level of abstraction such as a repository which calls the WCF service.

Repository which calls the service

```
public ProductController(IProductRepository productRepository)
{
      _productRepository = productRepository;
}

public ProductRepository(ProductServiceClient client)
{
      _client = client;
}
```

Service directly in the controllers

```
public ProductController(ProductServiceClient client)
{
      _client = client;
}
```

The repository classes do nothing apart from call the methods exposed via the service.

Comment: My approach would be to only introduce an extra layer if it does something.  If you think your client side logic is straight forward, then just call the service from the controller and be done with it.  If you want to introduce a business layer within your client, only then implement "service layer" that orchestrates wcf call and neccessary business logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I am well confused about your question, but I am sorry if I have misunderstood. Hope my pointers will clear this up.

1. Repositories related to persistence and define a way to handle the
   infrastructure layer i.e. dealing with data (in memory repository,
   sql repository or generic one)
2. Services if you like use these repositories to perform the
   contractual operations such as getting the client in your case.
3. Services are called by clients or someone that requests services and
   service in turn calls the repository which in turn calls the data
   operations.

So you may need to change your wcf to work with repositories and let your controller call services..hope that helps

Comment: Sorry i prob got my naming of classes wrong.  
My architecture: MVC and Business rules specific to presentaion - WCF Service API - Business logic - Data Access(Repository pattern)

Comment: Business rules specific to presentation could be handled in a view model type paradigm. In fact some suggest that its a better way because a model completely defines an entity and in this case your business logic (is bound to your view) via view model and also allows to validation.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by doing the exact oposite - the WCF should call methods inside the repository.

The data layer should be universal, and should be able to be accessed through any means (wcf should be one, mvc website should be another, etc).

That way you can also unit test your projects, and it's easier to keep track of it. Wcf should be considered as an extra api to your program in this case.

I am more concerned of where the business rules should be stored, but I would vote for mvc controllers for business logic, and wcf services invoking those internally.

Comment: My architecture: MVC and Business rules specific to presentaion - WCF Service API - Business logic - Data Access - Repository

Comment: You can also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657835/asp-net-mvc-wf-wcf-service-layer-how-i-can-use-thats-all-in-one-project, but thats my suggestion!

Comment: Can u provide an example of an architecture you would use?